# Same output in in MySQL update with foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to update MySQL table with array.

The Tables has 4 fields. REGNO, BATCHNO, NAMES and ATTEN_SUM. The REGNO has the unique value.

```
$i = 0;

while($row_recordset = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {

echo "<tr>";

echo "  <td>{$row_recordset['REGNO']}</td>
        <td>{$row_recordset['NAME']}</td>

        <td><input type='text' name='atten_ave".$i."'></td>

     ";

echo "</tr>";

$i++;
```

Here's my html code for the previous page after the update page.

```
foreach($_POST as $textbox => $values) {

$query_update = "UPDATE `grades` SET `ATTEN_SUM` = '$values' WHERE `BATCHNO` = '$sessionbatch'";
if(mysql_query($query_update)) {
     echo 'SUCCESS';
       } else{
       die(mysql_error());
              }
}
```

$_POST is a array from dynamic inputs from the previous page.
Here's the example of my output in the table.

```
REGNO  |  BATCHNO       |   NAME       |    ATTEN_SUM
====================================================
  1    |  ARPA 00-055    |   Jason      |      99 
  2    |  ARPA 00-055    |   Mark       |      99 
  3    |  ARPA 00-055    |   Edgar      |      99
```

It updates all the rows with the last value that I input.

Comment: could you please also post the HTML you're using to send the post data? There are so many errors in your code that I'm feeling goosebumps!

Comment: I already update sir my question please see my html code.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
 //<input type='text' name='atten_ave".$i."' 
 <input type='text' name='atten_ave[]'...
```

php

```
//foreach($_POST as $textbox => $values) {
foreach($_POST['atten_ave'] as $textbox => $values) {
```

BUT this update is useless.  it just update all record use last textbox.

i think you need to pass name or id to php,
then sql query add something like 'where id="$_POST['ID']"...

```
*CHECK mysql injections.
```

Comment: btw, shouldn't it be name='atten_ave[".$i."]'

Comment: hi thanks for the reply but yeah it will update all record tha I input on the last textbox. Do I need to crete another query that select the unique value?

Comment: add hidden input name like name='ABC[]' to target row you want to edit..then query add LIKE id='$_POST['ABC'][$textbox]',you try try then tick this answer haha

Comment: $JOE LEE lemme try sir hehe

Answer (score 0):

Well as you said, REGNO is the unique key, but you are updating on BATCHNO, which is not unique, according to your output.

Comment: thanks for the reply but sir, Because I have many different BATCHNO in my table, and all I just want is to update all of the ATEN_SUM of same BATCHNO.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the WHERE clause carefully, (WHERE `BATCHNO` = '$sessionbatch') you'll understand that it DOES update the SAME row each time and thus you see the last update.

Print the query statement, It'll be much clear to you.

```
if(mysql_query($query_update)) {
  echo $query_update.'</br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

You should not use mysql_* functions anymore. They're [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli) and may potentially leave holes for [mysql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should learn to use either [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

2)

Your code is totally open to any possible mysql injection. You should use `mysql_real_escape_string` or see `1)` above.

3)

With `foreach($_POST)` you're iterating through every `$_POST` item. I'm assuming (maybe I'm wrong) that you're submitting data from an HTML form. Try `var_dump($_POST)` and you'll see there are many values that are not related to what you want to do. For example:

```
<input type=”submit” value=”Some value” name="update">
```

will result in PHP

```
echo $_POST["update"];
// result: Some value
```

if you could post the output of `var_dump($_POST)` we could all see what you're passing inside of the foreach loop and perhaps give more detailed solution.